# Why is AngularJS repeating the output from a Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have this Directive

```
(function () {

angular.module("qnlAngularApp").directive('boxDisplay', ['$log', function ($log) {

    var linkFn = function (scope, element, attributes) {

        scope.backgroundColor = (attributes["boxBackgroundColor"] ? attributes["boxBackgroundColor"] : "#ccc");
        scope.backgroundImage = (attributes["boxBackgroundImage"] ? attributes["boxBackgroundImage"] : "");
        scope.opacity = (attributes["boxOpacity"] ? attributes["boxOpacity"] : "1");
        scope.borderWidth = (attributes["boxBorderWidth"] ? attributes["boxBorderWidth"] : 0);
        scope.borderColor = (attributes["boxBorderColor"] ? attributes["boxBorderColor"] : "#000");
        scope.borderRadius = (attributes["boxBorderRadius"] ? attributes["boxBorderRadius"] : 0);
        scope.id = (attributes["id"] ? attributes["id"] : "12345");

        scope.heading = (attributes["boxHeading"] ? attributes["boxHeading"] : "Lorem Ipsum Heading");
        scope.icon = (attributes["boxIcon"] ? "<img src='" + attributes["boxIcon"] + "' sr-only='" + scope.heading + "' alt='" + scope.heading + "' title='" + scope.heading + "' />" : "");

        //scope.templateName = "angular/templates/" + (attributes["boxTemplate"] ? attributes["boxTemplate"] : "boxDisplay_Basic.html");

        scope.flexValue = (attributes["boxWidth"] ? attributes["boxWidth"] : "100");

        scope.backgroundStyle = "background-color: " + scope.backgroundColor + ";opacity: " + scope.opacity + ";" + ((scope.backgroundImage != "") ? "background-image: url('" + scope.backgroundImage + "');" : "");

        scope.borderStyle = ("border: solid " + scope.borderWidth + "px " + scope.borderColor + ";"); //+

        //((borderRadius > 0) ? "border-radius: " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px;" +
        //    "-moz-border-radius: " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px;" +
        //    "-webkit-border-radius: " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px " + borderRadius + "px;" : "");
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: function (elems, attrs) {
            return "angular/templates/" + (attrs["boxTemplate"] ? attrs["boxTemplate"] : "boxDisplay_Basic.html");
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: linkFn
    };

            }]);
}())
```

And this Template

```
<div flex="{{flexValue}}" id="{{id}}" class="box" style="borderStyle}};{{backgroundStyle}}">
<div layout="column">
    <div layout="row">
        {{icon}}
        <h3>{{heading}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" ng-transclude>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Index.html file

```
<body ng-app="qnlAngularApp">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div layout="row" class="boxRow">
        <box-display box-width="33" id="1" box-background-color="#aaa" box-heading="First">See this box display</box-display>

        <box-display box-width="33" id="2" box-border-radius="5" box-heading="Second" box-border-width="5" box-template="boxDisplay_alt.html">See this box display too</box-display>

        <box-display box-width="33" id="3" box-template="boxDisplay_alt.html" box-heading="Third">See this box display three</box-display>
    </div>


    <div layout="row">

    </div>
    <div layout="row">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Why does it display the same result in all three DIVs? Is it caching issue? Async issue? Optimization issue? Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the directive's `scope` property is undefined, which is falsy. [A falsy value for the scope will mean the directive will use its parent's scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-). Your boxes all share the same scope because:

- the `scope` parameter is falsy
- all three of your boxes have the same parent
- those elements don't use any other directives that create a new scope

Therefore they will all display the save values.

To solve it, just change your directive to return this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: function (elems, attrs) {
        return "angular/templates/" + (attrs["boxTemplate"] ? attrs["boxTemplate"] : "boxDisplay_Basic.html");
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    link: linkFn
};
```

Note the line `scope: true,`

Comment: @user1872371 Added an example solution to the answer. You could also solve it by using another directive on the same element that created its own scope. But don't go out of your way to do that unless you need another directive there.